# How can I test that a service is listening on TCP with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, tcp

**Summary**: How can I use Node.js to see whether something is listening on a given port?

**Details**:

I am writing tests for an HTTP-based application in Node.

I've extended Node's `http.Server` with `util.inherits`, and in the resulting "class" wrap the standard `.listen()` functionality in a method of my own called `.start()`. This method performs some setup (e.g. connects to MongoDB) and then calls `http.Server.listen(port, cb)` when everything is good to go.

My problem: I'd like to write a test that calls `.start()` and then checks that the server is, indeed, listening on the specified port. I would like to do this without sending an HTTP request for the server to field. I just want to test that the server is listening.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with TCP, but given my experience with port scanning and `netstat` and things of that nature, I have the impression that *something* in Node's [net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) package will let me do this. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just use the `.listen()` callback and trust that Node.js' own unit tests will catch problems with it?

Comment: @Brad, a couple reasons: (i) I want to learn how to use TCP and the `net` package; (ii) I want to write a test suite that can determine whether the server was started or stopped without tapping into any other functionality. It's not that I distrust Node's listening or the tests thereof, but I want to be able to know that it happened, _programmatically_.

Comment: Have you tried the simple example in the documentation?  It's very straightforward.  http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectionlistener

Comment: Not yet, I will though. Sometimes you just want to run things past the community, to see if there's a "right" or "better" or even "best" way you're missing.

Comment: @Brad, thought about your comment and read up on mock objects—I see what you mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use net.connect():

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8124},
function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  client.end();
});
```

[Node.JS documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener) on `net` module

Comment: according to the documentation I believe you meant `net.createConnection` instead `net.connect` https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectlistener

you could also just use `net.connect(port[,host][,connectListener])`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what node.js offers, but here's a way to test if something is listening on a port without establishing a connection to it:

> This technique is often referred to as half-open scanning, because you don't open a full TCP connection. You send a SYN packet, as if you are going to open a real connection and then wait for a response. A SYN/ACK indicates the port is listening (open), while a RST (reset) is indicative of a non-listener.

This comes from the [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html) port scanning tool, and if you are interested in low-level TCP/IP stuff, there's a lot more to find on its website.

Comment: Thank you Marko for this detail! This explains further what the `allowHalfOpen` options `net.Server` construction is all about. The docs just say: `If allowHalfOpen is true, then the socket won't automatically send a FIN packet when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet. The socket becomes non-readable, but still writable. You should call the end() method explicitly. ` So, indeed, you can construct `net.` or `http.Servers` that respond this way, but with further caveats. I wont' be changing my instantiation code just for testing, but this is very useful info. Thank!

Answer (score 2):

Why? You only care if something is listening if you want to connect to it. So, connect to it, and handle the error. "Don't test, use." This applies to any resource. The best way to test whether it is available is to try to use it.

Comment: Appreciate your seasoned perspective, @EJP. The point you make is obviously not one to argue, seeing that it makes a lot of sense. That said, I am—perhaps unnecessarily—writing a spec by way of tests, and I'd like to be able to satisfy tests and isolate dependencies as much as possible. A part of this is purely academic, as I've already done what you've suggested: I already have a set of non-unit, functional tests using the HTTP client that just run through the client API calls. Obviously, if the service is not listening then you won't get HTTP responses :D