# How to know if instance of `http.Server` in node is already listening

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an http server and a piece of code that needs to run only when the server is listening. For this, I am binding to the `"listening"` event like so :

```
server.on('listening', doSomething)
```

The thing is that my server might be already listening and then the event `"listening"` will not be emitted, and my code won't run ... Is there a way to know the status of the server? Something like :

```
if (server.isListening() === true) doSomething()
else server.on('listening', doSomething)
```

**EDIT** I could of course (as suggested in an other similar question) try to connect to that port and see if somebody's listening. But that wouldn't prove that the particular instance I am using is listening. Just that **some** service is listening there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test that a service is listening on TCP with Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008073/how-can-i-test-that-a-service-is-listening-on-tcp-with-node-js)

Comment: yes ... pretty close, but not fully satisfying (see edits)

Comment: From the little I know, this is as close as you'll get.. Doesn't seem that node provides a method to check it. I'll be following to see if you'll get a better answer, its an interesting question

Comment: I assume `http.Server` maintains some internal state ... so I'm wondering why it's not exposed...

Comment: please considering accepting the `server.listening` answer now that it's more relevant

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple

```
if (server.listening) { # }
```

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listening

**Elaboration**

- [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver) has a `listening` attribute indicating whether the
  server is listening
- [http.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserver) inherits [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, in the modern world

Answer (score 7):

When using an instance of `http.createServer` the [`address()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) function is available to the server instance. This indicates whether or not the actual server is listening and available.

Until `listen()` is called on the server instance `address()` returns a `null` because the instance itself does not yet have an address it is listening on.

Once `listen()` is called though, `address()` will return an object.

#### Example

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();

console.log(server.address()); // This will be null because listen() hasn't been called yet

server.listen(3000, 'localhost', function() { 
    console.log('listening'); 
});

console.log(server.address()); // { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }
```

#### Summary

If `server.address()` is `null`, your instance is not running.
If `server.address()` returns an object, your instance is running.

Comment: No I don't want to start the server. Another part of the program handles this. And this other part might run before or after, I can't know in advance...

Comment: though I could also refactor the rest of the code to always call `listen` ... hopefully multiple calls to listen don't fckup things

Comment: If you stored the returned object from `server.listen()` in the actual section of code that is handling the start of your server, you could just check to see if that object is `undefined` or not. So in my example, if `listenInfo` has a value then an instance of my server is indeed running. This would satisfy your question.

Comment: Do you mean that the returned value is different when server is already listening or not? Though that wouldn't really solve my problem ... I would still have to call `listen` to get that return value

Comment: If your server is not listening, the value of `server.address() ` is `null`, if your server is listening `server.address()` would contain the hostname/ip, ip protocol, and port within an object. So you can indeed check if your server instance is actually listening. Until `listen()` is called `address()` is null. See these [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021045/tutorialspoint-restful-api-example-not-working-node-js/33023945#33023945)

Comment: Alright! `address()` method is what I was looking for then! Update your answer and I'll accept it. The current one doesn't answer as it requires a call to `listen` which I said I don't want to do.

Comment: Updated answer to be aligned with comments.